# Symfony2 Doctrine DB: Many-To-Many or 2 One-To-Many

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Please forgive me as I am a beginner to doctrine. I am writing an application to parse some sports data.

I have a simple OneToMany **Team** in relationship to **Players**.

```
class Team
    {

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Player", mappedBy="team")
     */
     protected $players;
```

However, I am now creating my Game entity which should have exactly two team objects--a visiting and a home team. To me this seems as two unique one-to-many relationships, but maybe I am overthinking and it would easier as a many-to-many relationship instead.

I would appreciate help in correctly building the entities for this configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Game class you should create two object with ManyToOne like this:

```
/**
 * @var Team
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Team")
 */
private $homeTeam;

/**
 * @var Team
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Team")
 */
private $awayTeam;
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thank you very much.